# How to move from one textFields to next textField on tabBar button's Action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitextfield

In my iphone app I have 6 textFields, and a tabBar (having 3 buttons Next,Previous,Done).

All I need to do is when I click on next button, the focus should move from first textField to next textField.

On Next button's IBAction I write the following code :

```
if ([txt1 isFirstResponder]==YES) {

    NSLog(@"TXT1");

    [txt1 resignFirstResponder];

    [txt2 becomeFirstResponder];

}
else if ([txt2 isFirstResponder]==YES) {

    [txt2 resignFirstResponder];

    [txt3 becomeFirstResponder];

}
else  if ([txt3 isFirstResponder]==YES) {

    [txt3 resignFirstResponder];

    [txt4 becomeFirstResponder];

}
else  if ([txt4 isFirstResponder]==YES) {

    [txt4 resignFirstResponder];

    [txt5 becomeFirstResponder];

}
else  if ([txt5 isFirstResponder]==YES) {

    [txt5 resignFirstResponder];

    [txt6 becomeFirstResponder];

}
else  if ([txt6 isFirstResponder]==YES) {

    [txt6 resignFirstResponder];

}
```

when I use this code NSLog prints infinite times.

What can be done??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, its my mistake. I Forgot to connect textField's delegate to Files Owner..
Thank you guys.

Comment: try not create an answer for your mistake, try edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Might be because if `txt1 isFirstResponder`, you're setting txt2 as firstResponder, then checking if txt2 is first responder.  You should put a `break;` at the end of each `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in each if statement, you do not need the `resignFirstResponder`, since you do not want to dismiss the keyboard each time you move to another field.

Instead, leave the only `resignFirstResponder` in `txt6`